# Delete files by date and character count

Tags: powershell, scripting, batch

I have an interesting problem. I need to delete directories that are older than x days but are only numerical. We have a log folder that has log files that we need to delete but other files and folders are also stored in the same locatin.. Normally i would do PS scripts to delete all directories over x amount of days but i can delete all folders. I only need to delete folders that are fully numeric.

Wanted to see if anyone had any ideas?

Comment: What's the general format of the folder name you want to delete?

Comment: Your question does not make sense / is not consistent. For example, it is not clear if you are deleting files or folders, and the 2nd to last sentence makes no sense.  You also never actually ask a a question. Please edit to clarify your intent and ask a proper question.

Comment: Fully numeric? `$_.Name -notmatch "\D"`?

Comment: sorry, I am deleting folders.

Answer (score 0):

$root = 'C:\logs'

Get-ChildItem -Path $root |
Where-Object {
    $*.name -match "^\d*$" -and
    $*.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Adddays(-45)
} |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force